# selecting rows the id's of which appear in a column of another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I can't quite get my head around a SQL query because it is not my forté. I'm trying to select the names of rows in an employees table the `id`'s of which appear in a column `salesPersonId` of another table, `accounts`. That is, any employee name which is represented in the accounts table.

```
ACCOUNT
+----+---------------+
| id | salesPersonID |
+----+---------------+
|  0 |     1020      |
+----+---------------+
|  1 |     1020      |
+----+---------------+
|  2 |     1009      |
+----+---------------+


EMPLOYEE
+------+---------------+
|  id  |   firstName   |
+------+---------------+
| 1009 |     BILL      | <-select his name
+------+---------------+
| 1020 |     KATE      | <-select her name
+------+---------------+
| 1025 |     NEIL      | <-not this guy
+------+---------------+
```

Since Neil hasn't got any presence in account.salesPersonID, I'd like to select the other two besides him. I'm not getting very far with it though, and looking for some input.

```
SELECT * FROM employee e
LEFT JOIN account a
ON a.salesPersonID = e.id
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(salesPersonID) FROM account) > 0
```

does not work. I wonder how I could select these employee names that are present in `salesPersonID`. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT Distinct e.firstName 
FROM employee e
JOIN account a ON a.salesPersonID = e.id
```

The `JOIN` will take care of the filtering to make sure that you are only returning the records that exist in both tables.

`Distinct` will make sure that you are only getting each `firstName` value one time. You can also accomplish this by Grouping by `employee.Id` or `employee.firstName` (grouping by Id is the better strategy if you want to return one row for each unique employee, even if they have the same first name, grouping on `firstName` or using `distinct` is for when you just want one of each unique name, even if the name is used by more than one employee)

Comment: wow, fantastic. Thank you so much! I'm still not quite getting how I would group if I had more than one Kate however..

Comment: If you have more than one Kate, and you only want to show one row for each unique name, then `Group By e.firstName`. If you want to show one row for each unique employee, even if employees have the same name, then `Group By e.Id`.

Comment: `SELECT Distinct e.firstName 
FROM employee e
JOIN account a ON a.salesPersonID1 = e.id
Group By e.Id` gives me the error: `ERROR: Column 'employee.FirstName' is invalid in the select list
because it is not contained in either an aggregate function
or the GROUP BY clause.` :/

Comment: So make that `Select e.firstName FROM employee e JOIN account a ON a.salesPersonID1 = e.id Group By e.Id, e.FirstName` (dont need the `distinct` anymore if you are grouping)

Answer (score 0):

u can have the query like this....

select e.firstname from employees1 e left join account a on(e.id=a.salespersonid)
where e.id= a.salespersonid 
group by e.firstname

result:

firstname
bill
kate